# PyQt Graphs can't plot values -- error reading lists

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, plot, graph, pyqt

```
        mes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
        IGVj = [2.2, 3.1, 3.5, 2.1]
      
        x = mes

     
        y = IGVj

     
        print("X é:", x) #output [1,2,3,4]
        print("Y é:", y) #output [2.2,3.1,3.5,2.1]

        StatusAPIUX_avaliador.graphicsView.plot(x, y)
```

[With "mes" and "IGVj" values defined manually it works on plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chSt7.png)

[With "mes" and "IGVj" value defined manually it works on plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjRBt.png)

But when i do by default

```
        mes = dados_listados[i][1] #first iteration is 1
        IGVj = dados_listados[i][3] #first iteration is 2.2
        x = mes

        y = IGVj

        print("X é:", x) #output 1
        print("Y é:", y) #output 2.2

        StatusAPIUX_avaliador.graphicsView.plot(x, y)
```

It doesnt load graph and crashes:

```
 raise Exception('When passing two unnamed arguments, both must be a list or array of values. (got %s, %s)' % (str(type(args[0])), str(type(args[1])))) Exception: When passing two unnamed arguments, both must be a list or array of values. (got <class 'int'>, <class 'float'>)
```

Before error shows, the output:
[With "mes" and "IGVj" value defined automatic it doesnt works on plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZXXQ.png)

Edit1: Trying the @musicamante option, i forgot to add that i tried, still doesnt work, it doesnt give error, but doesnt plot

```
        mes = dados_listados[i][1] #first iteration is 1
        IGVj = dados_listados[i][3] #first iteration is 2.2
        x = [mes]
        y = [IGVj]

       print("X é:", x)
       print("Y é:", y)
       StatusAPIUX_avaliador.graphicsView.plot(x, y)
```

[It shows empty plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2X8f.png)

[Go for all iterations but doesnt show errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2X8f.png)

Comment: The error seems pretty clear, the function expects lists, you're providing integers. Try with `x = [mes]` and `y = [IGVj]`.

Comment: Perfect, i was involved to edit and show that i had already tried your option, now reproducing it still doesnt come to any error and doesnt plot any value